# how to specify class (not string) in android layout data binding

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding

I have added a new binding rule like this for ImageView which takes a custom object:

```
@BindingAdapter({"custDrawable"})
public static void setCustDrawable(@NonNull ImageView view, HexDrawableModel model) {
    view.setImageDrawable(new HexDrawable(model));
}
```

where `HexDrawable` extend `Drawable`, and

```
data class HexDrawable(val text: String, val color: Color)
```

So... I am not sure how to use this binding adapter in my layout file because it is expecting a class not string. Please let me know to use this binding adapter (if it is even possible).

In layout XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    custDrawable=??? />
```

Comment: pass your HexDrawableModel through data binding and in your xml just send that variable your image view will be automatically be passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should declare them like this

```
@BindingAdapter("custDrawable")
public static void setCustDrawable(@NonNull ImageView view, HexDrawableModel model) {
    view.setImageDrawable(new HexDrawable(model));
}
```

And use them like this

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
       ...
    </data>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:custDrawable="@{yourVariableHere}/>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `app:custDrawable={$variable}`

define the variable in `data` section of the layout and bind it in respective java file